# Calculate how much has been scrolled

Tags: android, android-layout, scrollview

Is there a way to find out how much a scroll view has been scrolled?  Sort of like a pointer in a random access file?

Answer (score 0):

Checkout scrollView.getScrollY()

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getScrollY()